# Change Ruby Environment in Hudson

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, development-environment, hudson

I'm trying to point the Hudson app at the test environment in my MySQL database with Rails.    Do I need to change the environment variable RUBY_ENV?  If so, where do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're referring to `RAILS_ENV` variable? If you're writing the commands to hudson then something like this might work:

```
$ rake test RAILS_ENV=test
```

Although `rake test` implicitly uses the test environment. If it's needed for other commands just pass `RAILS_ENV=test` to them.

Comment: So where do I implement this code?  I'm a total Rails/Hudson newbie.

Comment: When you're editing project details, enter them [Build :: Execute Shell] text area.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I tried it and nothing different happened.  Hudson said that the build had no changes from the last one.  I entered that command in the Execute Shell text box and Saved it.